# Multiple JQuery $(document).ready functions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run two jQuery on the same page, I have found it is only possible to run one of them at any one time.

Is it possible to join them so both will run?

Here are the two functions I am trying to join:

Function 1

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#countdown_dashboard1').countDown({
        queue: false,
        targetDate: {
            'day': 9,
                'month': 1,
                'year': 2016,
                'hour': 11,
                'min': 0,
                'sec': 0
        }
    });
});
```

Function 2

```
<script id="addJS">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery.rsCSS3Easing.easeOutBack = 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)';
        $('#slider-with-blocks-1').royalSlider({
            queue: false,
            arrowsNav: true,
            arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
            fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
            controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
            controlNavigation: 'bullets',
            imageScaleMode: 'none',
            imageAlignCenter: false,
            blockLoop: true,
            loop: true,
            numImagesToPreload: 2,
            transitionType: 'move',
            keyboardNavEnabled: true,
            autoPlay: {
                enabled: true,
                delay: 8000,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                stopAtAction: false
            },
            block: {
                delay: 200
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ?? You can have as many "ready" handlers as you want. The library will run them in the order they appear.

Comment: Try putting both functions in the same "ready" block and see if they both run.  Maybe one is doing something you're not expecting.

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you really talking about the .ready functions or do you mean two jQuery versions?

Comment: Tip: you can simplify this syntax a bit. Instead of `jQuery(document).ready( function($) { ... } );`, simply write `jQuery( function($) { ... } );`. Functionally, the two are 100% equivalent - the second is just a little more concise.

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you post a jsFiddle (or similar) containing *all* of your code, including the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery(document).ready()` construct simply registers an event handler to the `ondomready` event of the `document` object. (The nuts and bolts are a little subtler than that, but that's basically accurate.)

And (for this event or any *other* event), you can register as many handlers as you like.

So, yes - you can do what you are asking.

Check the JavaScript console to see if you're getting any runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(document).ready(function () {});` just defers the execution of whatever its wrapping to when the document is considered ready.

From the docs (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

What you want is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#countdown_dashboard1').countDown({
        queue: false,
        targetDate: {
            'day': 9,
                'month': 1,
                'year': 2016,
                'hour': 11,
                'min': 0,
                'sec': 0
        }
    });

 jQuery.rsCSS3Easing.easeOutBack = 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)';

 $('#slider-with-blocks-1').royalSlider({
            queue: false,
            arrowsNav: true,
            arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
            fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
            controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
            controlNavigation: 'bullets',
            imageScaleMode: 'none',
            imageAlignCenter: false,
            blockLoop: true,
            loop: true,
            numImagesToPreload: 2,
            transitionType: 'move',
            keyboardNavEnabled: true,
            autoPlay: {
                enabled: true,
                delay: 8000,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                stopAtAction: false
            },
            block: {
                delay: 200
            }
  });
});
```